# Как прочитать содержимое ini-файла во время установки?

Tags: ini, inno-setup

Требуется во время установки прочитать значения из одного ini-файла и записать их в другой ini-файл. Функция для чтения строки из ini-файла почему-то возвращает переданное ей значение по умолчанию, а не значение из файла. Файл лежит там где надо, значения в нем есть.

Вот пример скрипта, воспроизводящий проблему:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp
AppVersion=1
DefaultDirName=D:\Projects\Test\
DisableDirPage=yes
Uninstallable=no

[INI]
Filename: "{app}\INIFile2.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key1"; String: "{code:GetIniFileValue|'Key1'}"
Filename: "{app}\INIFile2.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key2"; String: "{code:GetIniFileValue|'Key2'}"

[Code]
function GetIniFileValue(const Key: String): String;
begin
  Result := GetIniString('Section', Key, 'DefaultValue', 'D:\Projects\Test\INIFile1.ini');
  MsgBox(Result, mbInformation, MB_OK); // сообщение выводит результат функции GetIniString
end;
```

Содержимое файла `INIFile1.ini`:

```
[Section]
Key1=Value1
Key2=Value2
```

После выполнения установки появляется файл `INIFile2.ini` следующего содержимого:

```
[Section]
Key1=DefaultValue
Key2=DefaultValue
```

Как мне получить значения из первого файла?

Comment: Привет, есть пара комментариев по поводу описания метки [tag:inno-setup]. Во-первых, я не смог нагуглить этот текст, но все-таки уточню: он ведь не скопирован откуда-нибудь? Во-вторых, если это opensource, было бы здорово добавить ссылки на код и другие ресурсы (например, тематический форум или документацию).

Comment: А вообще, спасибо, что организуете информацию )

Comment: @NickVolynkin это перевод описания с английской версии SO. Там написано больше информации. Добавил ссылок, больше не осилил :)

Comment: Отлично, принял правки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в передаче параметров в функцию, параметры нужно было указывать без одинарных кавычек:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\INIFile2.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key1"; String: "{code:GetIniFileValue|Key1}"
Filename: "{app}\INIFile2.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key2"; String: "{code:GetIniFileValue|Key2}"
```

**UPD:** Нашел еще один отличный вариант чтения ini-файла без добавления кода.

```
Filename: "{app}\INIFile2.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key1"; String: "{ini:{app}\INIFile1.ini,Section,Key1}"
```